# Is it possible to retrieve list of public facebook profiles through the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to search for public facebook profiles in another app using graph API? So far what I've seen in documentation is that you need to know the User ID. I was thinking more in the lines of :

```
1) Enter Name
2) Get list of relevant profiles associated with that name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `/search` endpoint of the Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#search)

```
GET /search?q=barack%20obama&type=user
```

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I wanted. I know I know, I should've looked further down but I didn't...