# List of Facebook Users Containing a Particular Name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I wish to use the Facebook api to return a list of users contain a particular name:

For example, the following http search for the name Macallum:

https://www.facebook.com/search/results/?q=Macallum&type=users

gives the desired result. However I wish to do this using the api. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answer I gave here: [Is it possible to retrieve list of public facebook profiles through the Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936335/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-list-of-public-facebook-profiles-through-the-graph-ap/24936712#24936712)

You can use the `/search` endpoint to search for names.